# ${\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}-2\cdot y}={4\cdot x\cdot e^ {- 3\cdot x }-17\cdot e^ {- 3\cdot x }}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have the equation $${\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}-2\cdot y}={4\cdot x\cdot e^ {- 3\cdot x }-17\cdot e^ {- 3\cdot x }}$$ I think my substitude of $y_p$ is wrong and I  do not know why.

I tried subtitude private solution as following:

$y_p(x)= (AX+B)e^{-3x}+De^{-3x}$

but at the end of the proccess I have 3 unknown with 2 equations. I think it is something with the polynomial cooficent I did.

Comment: You can take e^(-3x) common, and it becomes (AX+B+D)(e^(-3x)). There is no need to consider two variables B and D. Instead of (B+D) just consider C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the RHS is $(4x-17)e^ {- 3x }$, the term $De^{-3x}$ is useless and it suffices to consider
$$y_p(x)= (Ax+B)e^{-3x}.$$
After the substitution we find,
$${\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y_p}{\mathrm{d} x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d} y_p}{\mathrm{d} x}-2\cdot y_p}=(4Ax+4B-5A)e^{-3x}.$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. Your substitution is not wrong. The coefficient of $e^{-3x}$ is $B+D$ and after the substitution you find a linear system which is indeterminate. Since you are looking for a PARTICULAR solution you can take $D=0$ (actually you may assign any value to $D$) and find $B$. The sum $B+D$ will be always the same!

Comment: I agree that I can write $(4x-17)e^ {- 3x }$ than it is much easy to recognize the subtitude. but I do not understand why my substitude is wrong?

Comment: Your substitution is not wrong.  You have that the coefficient of $e^{-3x}$ is $B+D$ and  the linear system is indeterminate. Since you are looking for a PARTICULAR solution  you can take $D=0$ (or assign any value) and find $B$.

Comment: but if I can choose any value for $D$ and than find $B$ it means that I have endless solution to this differential equation, and if I will have boundary conditions it will contradict with the uniquines theorem (I guess I wrong in my assumption but not sure where)

Comment: No, when you assign a value to $D$ then there is a unique value for $B$. The sum $B+D$ is always the same!

Comment: Ok, now I understood it, thank you very much!